# post json_encode data to other page

Tags: php, json

I have a file named user.php where i am encoding json data.

```
echo $json = json_encode(utf8_encode($user));
```

I want to send the $json value to other pages data.php,menu.php,content.php which are on different servers...i am opening these pages on a click event.

How can i pass $json from user.php to other pages?

Comment: Via what medium? an include? a post? a get?

Comment: why do you need to pass this to data.php? Is the file not local in the same dir?

Comment: If it's on the same server, hold it in `$_SESSION`.

Comment: It is in a different directory. I tried using curl...but din't quite help me. I want to do a POST

Comment: do you need to be directed to the pages in the browser?

Comment: If possible, consider shared session based on memcached. as an elegant solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Create a php file called sendjson.php (like below) and do a CURL POST (*it's always helped me in similar situations*). Make all your hyperlinks point to this page, each sending the url (without http://) and the json data).

```
<?php

 // In sendjson.php

 // Set data
 $json = $_GET['json'];

 //set destination page
 $url = $_GET['url'];

 // complete the url
 $url = "http://".$url;

 //create key value array
  $fields = array('jdata'=>urlencode($json));

     //build param string
     foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { 
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
    }

     // finish it
     rtrim($fields_string,'&');

     //POST to url


     //open connection
     $ch = curl_init();

     //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

     //execute post
     $result = curl_exec($ch);

     //close connection
     curl_close($ch);



?>
```

**Update:** If you are getting 301 errors with the above code (which worked for me), try checking that data.php/menu.php/content.php are all where they are supposed to be. And then, double check. Also, (*though I don't know if this is related*) you may want to make sure your $json data is not malformed.

Comment: I have edited the question. there are 3 pages where i want to pass $json. So i cannot use a header.

Comment: I tried your code. It throws me a document moved permanently 301 error.

Comment: @ads Just checked myself -- The code worked for me. The above code sent data from one remote server to my other remote server. But a 301 is a redirect notice meaning that the files were not found in that location. Did those php files on the remote folders move since?

Comment: These are the links in my user.php <div id="S"><a href="http://dev/abc" class="link"  target="blank"><p color="black" style="text-align: center;">Test</p></a></div>
 <div id="C"><a href="http://dev/def" class="link"  target="blank"><p color="blank" style="text-align: center;">Test1</p></div>
 <div id="M"><a href="http://dev/ghi" class="link"  target="blank"><p color="blank" style="text-align: center;">Test2</p></div> I want to post $json on click of all of these

Comment: @ads Oh i see. So, put the code I wrote above into a php file called sendjson.php. Then make your hyperlinks like this <a href="sendjson.php?url=somesite.com&json=".$json.">Click Me</a>.

Comment: @ads I updated my answer again to show sendjson.php please try this and let me know how it goes for you.

Comment: i cannot pass json variable in url... <div id="abc"><a href="sendjson.php?url=http://dec/etc&json=<?php echo $json;?>" class="link"  target="blank"><p color="black" style="text-align: center;">abc</p></a></div>....It does not pass the $json value